# Applescript: Repeat until reCaptcha occurs

Tags: applescript, recaptcha, repeat

I am pretty new in coding, especially with applescript. I managed to make the following code work:

```
tell application "Safari"

    repeat
        delay 7.5
        set the URL of document 1 to "https://url.com"
        delay 2
        tell document 1
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"id1\").click()"
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"id2\").click()"
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"id3\").click()"
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"id4\").click()"
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"id5\").click()"
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"id6\").click()"
            delay 0.25
        end tell
        tell application "Safari"
            activate
        end tell

        tell application "System Events"
            delay 0.25
            tell process "Safari" to key code 48
            delay 0.5
            key code 21

        end tell

        delay 0.25

        tell application "Safari"

            tell document 1
                do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"book\").click()"

            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat

end tell
```

Instead of repeating the code all the time I would like to make the code repeat until the Google reCaptcha occurs which pops up after the last javascript action.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to restructure your repeat statement like this...

```
set done to false
repeat while not done

    if reCaptcha = "something" then
        set done to true
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: I still don't know what I should insert for "something"

Comment: "something" is whatever you're testing for. You're trying to test if the captcha has changed? I'm not understanding exactly what you're trying to do. I was only helping with the `repeat` portion of the script.